# TCP socket communication from client to load balancer

Tags: sockets, tcp

I am trying to test the performance of a client\server application that uses TCP communication.

1. If I trigger multiple requests from the client, would it flow through the same connection\pipe to the server or would it open separate connections for each request.
2. Trying to understand, if we need multiple machines to emulate real-time testing or will each request from the client open separate connection.

Thanks
Anna

Comment: How it operates will entirely depend on how you code it. It's likely that in the real world you'd send requests over an existing connection, as performing the TCP handshake on eack new connection per request would add quite a bit of latency.

Answer (score 0):

It's entirely possible to do both -

1. Use same connection to send data on the same socket. eg. If you are using a tool like `ab`, it allows a keep-alive option where you can use the same socket. There may be other tools that will most likely offer similar options.

2.You could also specify `concurrency` ie. the number of connections to open to perform testing.

So ideally you'd not need multiple machines when you are trying to make up to 1000s of connections from one machine. But if you are trying to run 10's of thousands of clients,you *may* have to use multiple machines (in that case available network bandwidth of a single machine itself could be a bottleneck).

You should read man pages of `iperf` or `ab` for more details.